# IRM enabled different for interface than with powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell, library, irm

Learning about IRM and how it works, please help me understand this situation.

**Why does powershell show that IRMenabled is true, but the web interface doesn't reflect that IRM is being used?**

IRM is available on the site collection; the library located at the root site has IRM available but the box for "Restrict permission to document on the library on download:" is unchecked.
A Powershell query returns with IRMenabled as *true* and IRMExpire is true (has an expiration date).

I would have expected the interface to have the "restrict permission...." box checked if the IRMenabled property is true.

Additional information:

- Using SharePoint 2010.
- IRM is enabled in central admin for the farm
- IRM Expiration date on the library has a date for a few months ago.
- The library contains 2 documents.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of leaving this question with a conclusion:

The best I can determine is that at one point IRM was used and has either (1) the time limit on it expired so it's "on" technically but nothing is impacted or (2) at one point it was used and has been since turned off but some residual settings are still around.

Personally, I suspect the former.